# React Native: Removing the bottom border from NavigatorIOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigator-ios

I have a `NavigatorIOS` that draws a gray border bottom and I can't remove it nor change it's color.

[image]

How can I remove it? My React Native version is 0.44.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the prop `shadowHidden` in `NavigatorIOS` to true. [See docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#shadowhidden)